# How to count total number of lines of found files?

Tags: linux, bash, find

I'm running a `find . -name pattern` to find some files, and I'd like to elegantly get the total number of lines in these files.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If your version of `wc` and `find` support the necessary options:

```
find . -name pattern -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=-
```

which will give you per-file counts as well as a total. If you want only the total:

```
find . -name pattern -print0 | wc -l --files0-from=- | tail -n 1
```

Another option for versions of `find` that support it:

```
find . -name pattern -exec cat {} + | wc -l
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ find . -name '*.txt' -exec cat '{}' \; | wc -l
```

Takes each file and `cat`s it, then pipes all that through `wc` set to line counting mode.

Or, [untested] strange filename safe:

```
$ find . -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 cat | wc -l
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the output of :

`find . -iname "yourpattern" -exec cat '{}' \; |wc -l`

inserts extra lines. In order to get a reliable line count you should do:

`find . -name "yourpattern" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l`

This way you handle spaces correctly, get a line count for each file, and the total line count, faster and in style!!!

Comment: e.g. : time find . -name "*.m" -exec cat '{}' \; | wc -l runs in 4.878s and returns 227847 as line count . But time find . -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 wc -l runs in 0.769s and returns the proper line count 126464 .

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way to find no. lines in a file:

```
wc -l filename
```

Example:

```
wc -l myfile.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

Untested, but how about something like:

```
cat `find . -name "searchterm" -print` | wc -l
```

Comment: This will not work well with paths containing spaces or characters that trigger globbing.

Answer (score -2):

```
wc -l `find -name filename`
```

will work efficiently.

Comment: … or not, if paths contain spaces or characters that trigger globbing.

Comment: And even if it works, this reports the number of lines *in **each** file,* which is not an elegant way to get the total (as requested).